# How to define a research question when the output is a product, used in research?

Tags: research

My school requests a research question for a project. I came up with one like this: (different topic but very similar, due to NDA)

> What is the behavior of a bike, depending on speed, time in use and temperature?

This question is about the research, and defines what is wanted. However this is way too much for the time I will work at the project. My task is to design, build and verify the bike.

If I leave the research question as it is, I will be having trouble at the end, because I cannot answer it.

Rephrasing the question to something like below feels not right, it does not contain the whole assignment. Must a research question really be a question, or can it also be a statement?

Question:

> How do you build a bike?

Statement:

> Build and verify a bike.

EDIT:

The project is done at a company by me as a bachelor assignment. The company has a problem which is pretty hard to solve (my part of the project won't solve it either). To further investigate the problem they need this bike.

I don't really have a clue how this research question is used in these kind of assignments where it is `build and verify x`. Usually the research question is defined at the beginning, and in your conclusions at the end of the project you are able to give an answer.

Comment: Can you tell us more about why this research is required? How the questions are generally used? Who does this research?

Answer (score 1):

You are **constructing a prototype**. This prototype must serve in resolving the question you quoted, and this is pretty much what you must ask about:

> "What prototype bike is suitable for research of..."
>
> "Is prototype X of bike suitable for research..."
>
> "How to construct a prototype of bike suitable for research..."
>
> "How to adapt a [generic brand bike] as a suitable prototype for tests in research..."